# Overload class member function marked const

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am having trouble overloading class member functions that are marked `const`, while there is no problem when the functions are not marked `const`. Also the overload itself works fine in pure C++.

The following fails

```
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>


class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(){};

  std::vector<double> bar(const std::vector<double> &a) const
  {
    return a;
  }

  std::vector<int> bar(const std::vector<int> &a) const
  {
    return a;
  }
};


namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
    .def("bar", py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>(&Foo::bar));
}
```

Compiled using:

```
clang++ -O3 -shared -std=c++14 `python3-config --cflags --ldflags --libs` example.cpp -o example.so -fPIC
```

Gives error:

```
...  
no matching function for call to object of type 'const detail::overload_cast_impl<const vector<double, allocator<double> > &>'
    .def("bar", py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>(&Foo::bar));
...
```

Whereas the code works when I remove the `const` mark of the functions.

How should I perform this overload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special tag for const overloaded methods.

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
    .def("bar", py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>(&Foo::bar, py::const_));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (I will accept when SO allows me in a few min)